# cURL get Content from https Domain

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get information (page content) from a domain with https.

```
$ch = curl_init($line);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $homepage = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

This only throws the exception: ***400 Bad request***
*Your browser sent an invalid request*.

What option do I have to set or can I see what's the problem?

Comment: See the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option to get verbose output.

Comment: 400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out:

```
function get_ssl_site($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Hope this helps somebody